# document.write, Array.push and putting strings together

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I want my code to be able to replace the current HTML page seen by the user via document.write(). And it does replace the HTML page, it just doesn't show the text that I want it to show. If I use my code to add an element via the addElement() function,

```
function addElement(a, b) {
    var startTag, tagValue, endTag, finalTag;

    // htmlify
    if (b === undefined) {
        startTag = "<p>";
        endTag = "</p>";
    } else {
        startTag = "<" + b + ">";
        endTag = "</" + b + ">";
    }



    finalTag = startTag + tagValue + endTag;
    eio.push(finalTag);
};
```

it takes the parameters that the user has put in to create a valid tag, for example

```
addElement("This is a valid h1 tag.", "h1");
```

It then parses that into a HTML tag (variables filled out here),

```
var finalTag = "<" + "h1" + ">" + "This is a valid h1 tag." + "</" + "h1" + ">"
```

and pushes it into an array called eio (variables filled out again).

```
eio.push("<h1>This is a valid h1 tag.</h1>");
```

This array is not used until displayElements() is called, where I used a for loop to put all the different strings together. Here's how I did it:

```
function displayElements() {
    finalString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head><body>";
    for (i = 0; i === eio.length; i++) {
        finalString += eio[i];
    }
    finalString += "</body></html>";
    document.write(finalString);
};
```

Using our example again, finalString should look like this

```
finalString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head><body><h1>This is a valid h1 tag.</h1></body></html>"
```

when it we use it in the document.write() function. This *should* leave us with an HTML page where it says "This is a valid h1 tag." in big bold font, yet it only leaves us with a blank screen. One interesting thing however, is that the title does get updated when we call the function, but the page is still blank.

[You can see the entire code here](http://tufda.net/HTML.js/html.js), [and go to the example website here](http://tufda.net/HTML.js/print.html).

Comment: Your function uses a `tagValue` that is not passed in...

Comment: `i = 0; i === eio.length; i++` ? did you mean `<=`?

Comment: @Steve Not exactly, I can see it being used in the addElement function, where it is added to the finalTag variable...

Comment: @tufda `tagValue` is not an argument of `addElement`. You just declare it as a local variable... I think you want to assign your parameter `a` to `tagValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems were already pointed out by sabithpocker and me. I will sum those up to make this answer.

Your `addElement` method takes an argument `a` and does nothing with it. Instead you are using a local variable `tagValue`. You could fix it by assigning the value of `a` to `tagValue`.

```
function addElement(a, b) {
    var startTag, endTag, finalTag;
    var tagValue = a;

    // htmlify
    if (b === undefined) {
        startTag = "<p>";
        endTag = "</p>";
    } else {
        startTag = "<" + b + ">";
        endTag = "</" + b + ">";
    }

    finalTag = startTag + tagValue + endTag;
    eio.push(finalTag);
};
```

The second problem is a typo in the for-loop of your `displayElements` method. It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < eio.length; i++) {
    finalString += eio[i];
}
```